# Create a triangle width CSS

Tags: css, transform, transformation

Here you see a picture of a blue triangle. How can i make this with css. I can use a background image. Or how can i make it with CSS. Transform? The triangle is on the left by. But on the right is not. And it must be responsive.

Thanks

[image: Blue squere]

Comment: dude it's not tiangle , it's trapeze. And I doubt you can create it in css. Possible you could do with several masks cutting basic triange. But I see it wontwork in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I used one div and its after to create the lower part.

http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/anksv

or this is better as it requires single element with no pseudo elements.

```
.trapz{
  position:absolute;
   height: 50px; 
   width: 0px;
  background-color:transparent;
   border-left: 500px solid blue;
   border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
```